# Weird new line using \cmpd from chemnum in long headingtitles

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, chemnum

I have a problem using `\cmpd` in a heading, that is too long. For some weird reason, the compound number gets put on a new line, even though there is no need. I already have a workaround using `~`, but this is not what I want.
A little explanation: within `\iupac{}` you can add a possible breakpoint using `\|`. As you will see, the linebreak will be placed after (hydroxy), but the (1) will be put on a new line. I inserted two headings. The first is the one, giving me a headache, the second one is working fine. The fourth is the workaround.

Here is my (almost) MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Silbentrennung, etc.
\usepackage{chemnum} % provides \cmpd{Name.Sub}
\usepackage{chemmacros} % provides iupac and loads siunitx

\begin{document}

\subsection{\iupac{\tert\-Butyl 2\-((\S\-2,2\-dimethyl\-1,3\-dioxolan\-4\-yl)\|(hy\|droxy)\|methyl)\|acryl\|ate} (\cmpd{iPrtBuAcrylate})}
Problematic subsection heading.

\subsection{\iupac{Sodium \S\-2,2\-dimethyl\-1,3\-dioxolane\-4\-carboxylate} (\cmpd{iPrCarboxylate})}
Working subsection heading.

\subsection{\iupac{\tert\-Butyl 2\-((\S\-2,2\-dimethyl\-1,3\-dioxolan\-4\-yl)\|(hy\|droxy)\|methyl)\|acryl\|ate}~(\cmpd{iPrtBuAcrylate})}
Problematic subsection with a workaround.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: in headings you should use `\cmpd+{<id>}` in order to avoid that the numbering starts in the table of contents.

Comment: It's curious that if you add at the end `\|`, the bad line break doesn't happen. However, this doesn't happen with `article`; the difference is that `scrartcl` uses raggedright section titles.

Comment: @cgnieder actually, I am already using `\cmpd+` in my document. I don't know why I took it out again. ;) Thanks for the advice though!

@egreg this actually seems to be a simple workaround as well. Thanks!

Comment: @cgnieder I remember: I took the + out, because it would have lead to empty parentheses in the MWE. :)

Comment: @basseur yes, the `+` plus variant doesn't declare a label, it only refers to one. You'd have to declare it elsewhere then, e.g. somewhere in the text...

Comment: BTW: `\iupac` has nothing to do with `siunitx`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `chem` macros.  The default headings in `scrartcl` are set `\raggedright` via the command `\raggedsection`.  Ragged right environments demonstrate the problem you have.  One way around this is to use the `ragged2e` package and set `\raggedsection` to `\RaggedRight`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Averylongword\-averylongwordaverylong\-wordaverylongwordavery\-long\-word X}

\begin{flushleft}
  Averylongword\-averylongwordaverylong\-wordaverylongwordavery\-long\-word\-averylongwordaverylong\-wordaverylongwordavery\-long\-word X
\end{flushleft}

\let\raggedsection\RaggedRight

\subsection{Averylongword\-averylongwordaverylong\-wordaverylongwordavery\-long\-word X}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will this only affect the sectionheadings? What possibly bad repercussions are there to using this method?

Comment: `scrartcl` introduces `\raggedsection` explicitly for use in sectioning headings and uses this code nowhere else.  So this is the right command to customize.