# Hyphenation problem on very narrow column and \flushleft

Tags: horizontal-alignment, luatex, hyphenation

I have a strange problem with hyphenations, when the column is very narrow. My text is finnish and I'm using lualatex.

In my narrow column, I have words "Ympärileikkauksen liitto". It breaks up as follows:

```
Ympärileikkauk-
sen
liitto
```

So it hyphenates word "ympärileikkauksen" correctly, but then, after that, it breaks line although it would be correct behaviour if word "liitto" was on the same line, as:

```
Ympärileikkauk-
sen liitto
```

Without flushleft it seems to be correct. But I need flushleft elsewhere, so I cannot remove it.

Minimal example:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8".
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX} 
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä.

\begin{wraptable}{r}{59.94pt}\begin{flushleft}{\footnotesize \emph{Ympärileikkauksen liitto}}\end{flushleft}\end{wraptable}
Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä.
Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä. Kirjoitan paljon tekstiä.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134105/15925, it is a problem with `\raggedright`, and can be corrected by using `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package.

Comment: Also adding `\hspace{0pt}` at the start of the text, if using engines different from LuaTeX: the difference is that LuaTeX can hyphenate the first item of a paragraph, while TeX and XeTeX can't. Adding `\hspace{0pt}` avoids the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `flushleft` environment. Instead, load the `ragged2e` package and issue the commands

```
\begin{wraptable}{r}{59.94pt}
\RaggedRight
\footnotesize \emph{Ympärileikkauksen liitto}
\end{wraptable}
```

to get the string "Ympärileikkauksen liitto" typeset flush-left while preserving LaTeX's ability to hyphenate long words.

You mention you're using LuaLaTeX. If you were using XeLaTeX instead, you would have to add -- per egreg's recommendation -- `\hspace{0pt}` at the start of the long string, to ensure that the long word "Ympärileikkauksen" can get hyphenated.